# Order statistics: probability of second highest order statistic higher than first order statistic

Tags: order-statistics

Assume I have two bins with n items each iid drawn from the same F. How can I formulate the probability that the second-highest order statistic of the first bin is **higher** than the highest-order statistic of the other bin?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried / where you are getting stuck. You will find that people on this site will be significantly faster to help you if you do that; that way, we know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $F$ is continuous, one has $2n$ distinct items and one asks the probability that marking $n$ of these chosen randomly yields that two given items are marked. The probability that the first item is marked is $1/2$. Conditionally on this event, one must mark $n-1$ items amongst $2n-1$ hence the conditional probability that the second item is marked is $(n-1)/(2n-1)$.

Thus, the probability that the two highest valued items are in the first bin is $(n-1)/(2(2n-1))$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for just the formulation, I will just give you a suggestion on how I would set up the problem. Say $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are in the first bin, and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are in the second bin. Then the probability we are after is $P[X_{(2)} > Y_{(1)}]$. Note that we **cannot** replace $X_{(2)}$ with $Y_{(2)}$ even though they are independent and have the same distribution.

You may compute as an exercise that if $F$ is absolutely continuous (i.e. the random variables have a density $f$), then the pdf of $X_{(k)}$ or $Y_{(k)}$ in general is
$$
g_{(k)}(y) = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}[F(y)]^{k-1}[1-F(y)]^{n-k}f(y).
$$

Since $Y_{(1)}$ and $X_{(2)}$ are independent it follows that they have the joint density
$$
g(x,y)=g_{(2)}(x)g_{(1)}(y)
$$
and so
$$
P[X_{(2)} > Y_{(1)}] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_y^\infty g(x,y)dxdy
$$
has been reduced to an elementary computation.

If $F$ is not absolutely continuous a more careful approach must be taken.